# Move a directory in ColdFusion and Railo

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfdirectory

In Adobe ColdFusion (ACF), I've always used cffile action="rename" to move both files and directories. Not unreasonably, Railo doesn't think cffile applies to directories, so you need to use cfdirectory rename, and that works fine. However, that doesn't appear to work in ACF.

For example:

```
<cfdirectory action="RENAME" directory="C:/tmp/aaa1/aaa2/" newDirectory="C:/tmp/aaa2">
```

...works in Railo, but in ACF throws this:

```
The specified directory attribute C:/tmp/aaa1/aaa2/ cannot be renamed to newdirectory C:\tmp\aaa1\C:\tmp\aaa2.
```

So it seems you'd have to use cffile to move directories on ACF, and cfdirectory on Railo.
 Is that really the state of the art? Is there some way to get cfdirectory to move a directory on ACF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, but it works if you use backslashes.

I'd class this as a bug in CF (I'm testing with CF9.0.1) as for all other file operations I am aware of, either slash works fine on CF.

Comment: Interesting. Is that also true on 'nix? Ideally, I'm looking for constructs that work the same on ACF, Railo (and though I didn't mention it and haven't tried it yet, Open BlueDragon), on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Comment: Java (and by extension CF) on Windows will accept both types of slash as a file separator.  This is the only time I've seen it not work.  On \*nix one has to use a fwd slash.  However the ramification of this is that one can (well: *should*) be able to use a fwd slash with impugnity on both platforms.  So when writing cross-platform code: use a fwd slash.

Answer (score 1):

We developed an application in CF10 that used forward slashes for the file path in cfdirectory action="rename".

```
<cfdirectory action="rename" directory="//fileserver/folder10/test/TEST74036JJ_CW"  newdirectory="//fileserver/folder10/TEST74036JJ_CW">
```

This code appeared to run fine in CF10.

When we moved the code to a CF8 server, we received the same error with the newdirectory path being appended on to the end of the original directory.

> The specified directory attribute //fileserver/folder10/test/TEST74036JJ_CW cannot be renamed to newdirectory \\fileserver\folder10\test\fileserver\folder10\TEST74036JJ_CW

So, it does appear that CF10 can now handle forward slashes for cfdirectory action="rename".

Answer (score 0):

I get a solution only with a change. On the attribute newDirectory do not write the path, only write the new folder name and ready.  Try it. This was the option for me. I use coldfucion 9.0.1